# Is there a listener for adding or removing items of an SWT Combo?

Tags: java, combobox, swt

For an instance of `Combo`, is there a listener in SWT that fires when new items are added to the combo box or existing items are removed? Or in general, when the number of items changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such listener. If application code adds or removes items, it needs to notify interested parties on its own.

Comment: All right, thank you. I added my own ``ItemAddedListener`` and ``ItemRemovedListener`` based on SWT's ``Listener`` interface. Then, when items are added/removed, I call ``listener.handleEvent(new Event())`` in a loop to fire all observers that previously registered to the add/remove event.